# how to install IONIC with npm

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've some wrong on my installer IONIC on windows 10

When i do this in command prompt :

```
$ npm install -g ionic cordova
```

I've this error

> $ npm install -g ionic cordova   ^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

may someone can help me ??

Comment: Do you have npm already installed and can you run just `npm` in your command line? What does it give you? It is really unclear what you have done so far, aside from copy and pasting a command (which looks like it was intended for a linux-like system anyway).

Comment: It seems that you have some garbage characters after Cordova (^^^). Copy and paste exact: `npm i -g ionic cordova` and hit enter.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have some garbage characters after Cordova (^^^).

In Command prompt, type exact: `npm i -g ionic cordova` and hit enter.

Comment: @LYG, Please upvote the answer by clicking up directional triangle and click ✓ sign to show it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you have an up-to-date version of Node.js installed on your machine. If you don't have Node.js installed.
2. Open the command prompt and verify the Node.js version by using the command node -v.
3. To install Cordova and Ionic, use - `npm install -g cordova ionic.`

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g cordova

npm install -g ionic
```